# How to Add File Reference to Quality Issue

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

Via the BIM360 API, I am able to create Quality Issues and upload files (to be used as attachments). However, even though I am calling Post Attachments (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-attachments-POST/) (and all responses are good), nothing appears on the Issue screen.
[Issue screen with manually added file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXIBq.png) How can I make my attached file appear under the References->Files section?

(Note, I saw a mention elsewhere of the relationships API, but I get a random error just calling the first "asset" API [{"title":"Forbidden","detail":"Forbidden","errorCode":"GENERAL_ERROR","type":"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/assets/v1/error-codes/GENERAL_ERROR"}])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, the screenshot shows you are working with Issues in Autodesk Construction Cloud (ACC), while the API you are using is for BIM360 Issue. This API is NOT compatible with ACC.

To work with ACC Issue, the API is available at the category of ACC:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/issues-issues-GET/
this blog tells more.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/acc-issues-api-available-preview

In the context of ACC, the attachment(references) is managed by the general API (Relationship API). In Additional Tests of Postman collection of ACC Issue API, I demoed how to add Photo with the Issue. The logic is similar.
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-acc.issues.api-postman.collection

Firstly, use Data Management API to get the document urn. Then, use ACC Issue API to get id of one issue. finally, use Relationship API to bind them.

```
   PUT https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/relationship/v2/containers/{{project_id_without_b}}/relationships
```

P.s. -bim360- in the domains is just because of legacy design of the terminologies. It can work for the contexts of both BIM360 and ACC (note it is Relationship API can work within both of the contexts)

Payload:

```
    [
       {
         "entities": [
           {
             "domain": "autodesk-bim360-issue",
             "type": "issue",
             "id": "{{one_issue_id}}"
           },
           {
             "domain": "autodesk-bim360-documentmanagement",
             "type": "documentlineage",
             "id": "{{one_document_urn}}" 
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Dumb question, is there any such thing as a "BIM360 project"? (Or "Autodesk Build", as some resources say the name has changed to.) Whenever I try to find such a thing, it just forces me back to ACC; I am not sure how to separate the two. (My assignment was to "Push Issues to Autodesk Build/BIM 360 project within Autodesk Construction Cloud".)